# Excel function with multiple outputs WITHOUT array formulas

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Is it possible to define an Excel VBA function with multiple outputs and use it worksheet ranges WITHOUT array formulas?

Comment: Can you expand on why you don't want to use array formulas?

Comment: array formulas are difficult to modify/spread on the fly and to see which outputs correspond to each cell in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `xlwings` it is possible to define dynamic arrays:

http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html#dynamic-array-formulas

Answer (score 1):

Not really "multiple outputs", but you can use Application.Caller to figure out where your function is being called from, and return a single value based on (eg) what column the formula is in.

```
Function WhereAmI(rng As Range)
    Dim c, ws, rv
    Set c = Application.Caller 'cell containing the formula
    Set ws = c.Parent          'worksheet containing the formula

    Select Case c.Column
        Case 2: rv = "OK"
        Case Else: rv = "not OK"
    End Select

    WhereAmI = rv
End Function
```

But that's really not so different from having a number of different functions, and for anything complex it's going to be a lot less efficient than using array formulas.

Comment: You would enter it in a cell like any other user-defined formula. The return value will depend on which column the formula is entered in (as a simple example - it doesn't even look at the input parameter). If you want a more complex example then it would be useful to update your question with an example of the type of function you'd like to use (but don't want to use as an array formula)

Answer (score 1):

you can put multiple values into a string:

```
Public Function CircleStuff(r As Range) As String
    Dim diameter As Double, circumference As Double, area As Double
    Dim radius As Double
    radius = r.Value
    diameter = 2 * radius
    circumference = 3.1415926 * diameter
    area = 3.1415926 * radius * radius
    CircleStuff = CStr(diameter) & "," & CStr(circumference) & "," & CStr(area)
End Function
```

so if A1 contains:

1

=CircleStuff(A1) would return:

2,6.2831852,3.1415926

you could retrieve the individual pieces with FIND and MID functions.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: Well, you could do something like `A1=CalculateOutput1() & "," & CalculateOutput2()` and `B1=SomeFunction(Left(A1, Find(A1, ",") - 1), Right(A1, Len(A1) - Find(A1, ",")))`, but... I don't see why you'd want to.